# how to specify hibernate select query with where clause and ? placeholders

Tags: java, hibernate, web-applications, prepared-statement

Here is my code sample:

```
String hqlquery="select stName,stCode from StGroup where stName=?";
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(hqlquery);
ps.setString(1,stname);//here stname am passing through one function
ps.executeQuery();
```

This code gives me number of records that are selected.
But I want the list of records(containing stName,stCode)that match "stName"(in where clause).
How can I get the list.Can I use ResultSet with hibernate.

Comment: In short, you're asking how to execute HQL queries. [The documentation explains it](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-querying-executing).

Comment: My doubt is whether resultset can be used with hibernate or not?

Comment: What does the documentation say? What does the javadoc say? This is extremely easy to find out. No, ResultSet is a JDBC API, and can't be used with Hibernate. But Hibernate queries can return lists, or scrollable results.

Answer (score 0):

`PreparedStatement.executeQuery()` returns a `ResultSet` containing the rows that match your WHERE clause, each row containing the fields you put in the SELECT clause. With the `first()`, `last()` and `next()` methods of the ResultSet, you can access all this information: the result set is positioned in a current row and you can access the fields values through methods like `getString(columnName)` or `getInt(columnName)`, depending on the type of the column.